# Network resources (the doctor check crashed) X Due to an error,

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I cant create project, get pub or get dependencies.
when i try flutter doctor it gets stuck in trying to reach pub.dev and this shows:

`[☠] Network resources (the doctor check crashed) X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues. X Exception: Network resources exceeded maximum allowed duration of 0:04:30.000000 •`

Restart/shutdown PC done. I tried flutter upgrade, deleting the flutter and downloading it again still nothing the same.